# How to directly embed an flv in actionscript so ffmpeg can convert from the compiled swf?

Tags: actionscript, ffmpeg, flash, mxmlc

I have an flv that needs to be embedded into a swf. I am currently using the Embed tag and playing the flv with NetStream. The problem is that it does not seem to be directly embedding the flv file, as ffmpeg does not detect it. I am currently using mxmlc to compile. If published from Flash Professional the conversion works. I can't use Flash Professional because I need to use the command line. Is there a way to embed an FLV in actionscript and have ffmpeg convert it?